# how to get jenkins pipeline chioce param in environment section

Tags: jenkins

Now I am get chioce parameter in pipeline file like this:

```
pipeline {
            agent any
            parameters {
                choice(
                    name: 'env',
                    choices: ['fat', 'uat', 'pro'],
                    description: 'fat:test env\nuat:uat env\npro:pro env'
                )
               
            }
            tools {
                gradle "Gradle"
            }
            environment {
                registryAddr = getRegistryAddr("${params.env == null}" ? "fat" : "${params.env}",map)
            }
}
```

but the `params.env` is awalys get null, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

change the get function gramma in Groovy code like this should fix the problem:

```
 registryAddr = getRegistryAddr("${params.env}" == null ? "fat" : "${params.env}",map)
```